# How can I delete the whole lib directory during the update in install4j?

Tags: file, updates, uninstallation, install4j

During the update of my application, I want to delete the whole lib directory and install a new one. This is not possible with the "uninstall previous installation" action because in that case, other files that should be kept are being uninstalled as well. It is not possible to manually sellect the "... but not for update" uninstallation option because those files cannot be found in the distribution tree, since they are only be created during the first installation.So, the most suitable oprion seems to be the uninstallation of the lib directory but when I tried to do it, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "Delete files and directories" action for the lib directory to the installer before the "Install files" action.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need as Chara Paschalidi and looking for an action that could remove my folder (which happens to be called "lib" as well) found the "Delete files and directories" action.

But I have not immediately been successful: 
For the "files and directories" attribute I chose "directory" and then "lib", which is an immediate child of my installation directory. I repeated build and installation and found the same result as before: my new libraries were added to lib, but the previous (versions of) libraries were all still there.

Playing around with the options, I tried the **checkbox labelled "Recursive"** - and was lucky. With this and only with this checked did I get the expected result.

This seems not correct to me. The directory named "lib" has been chosen from the dialog, which shows the directory as part of the "distribution tree", so it should work. (Even if entered manually, it should have worked since as I understand the installation directory is the cwd during the installation process.) And my lib/ folder is certainly not farther below in the tree (in which case recursive search for it would have made sense to me).

Herr Kegel, would you comment on this?